# Windows to DB2 Connection: Connection authorization failure occurred. Reason: Local security service non-retryable error

Tags: db2, linux, windows, remote, db2-10.5

```
Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to TSMDB1. (Error: [jcc][t4][2010][11246][3.68.61] Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: Local security service non-retryable error. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000)
[jcc][t4][2010][11246][3.68.61] Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: Local security service non-retryable error. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000
Error creating JDBC Connection connection to TSMDB1. (Error: [jcc][t4][2010][11246][3.68.61] Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: Local security service non-retryable error. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000)
[jcc][t4][2010][11246][3.68.61] Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: Local security service non-retryable error. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000
```

Been trying to figure out why I can't connect to a DB2 server remotely.

- Linux USER has access to connect/query locally to a DB2 database
- Windows USER has access to connect/query locally to a DB2 database
- Windows can NOT successfully remotely connect to Linux DB2.

Troubleshooting:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago), 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64
- `Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.3`
- Firewall port is open (51500). Can telnet to it (From Windows to Linux).
- Same error using multiple methods (Datagrip, IBM Data Studio, etc)
- can connect to DB on local machine (Windows machine, local) with the same setup - so Datagrip/IBMDS works.
- I've [change my shadow password](http://www.torkwrench.com/2009/05/04/errorcode-4214-sqlstate28000-from-db2-on-ubuntu/) with `echo "USER:PASS" | chpasswd -c MD5`. Some people say that their program doesn't accept SHA512 and they have to downgrade to MD5. No effect

`get dbm cfg show detail`

```
db2 => get dbm cfg show detail

          Database Manager Configuration

     Node type = Enterprise Server Edition with local and remote clients

 Description                                   Parameter   Current Value              Delayed Value
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Database manager configuration release level            = 0x1000

 CPU speed (millisec/instruction)             (CPUSPEED) = 2.991513e-07               2.991513e-07
 Communications bandwidth (MB/sec)      (COMM_BANDWIDTH) = 1.000000e+02               1.000000e+02

 Max number of concurrently active databases     (NUMDB) = 32                         32
 Federated Database System Support           (FEDERATED) = NO                         NO
 Transaction processor monitor name        (TP_MON_NAME) =

 Default charge-back account           (DFT_ACCOUNT_STR) =

 Java Development Kit installation path       (JDK_PATH) = /home/tsminst1/sqllib/java/jdk64 /home/tsminst1/sqllib/java/jdk64

 Diagnostic error capture level              (DIAGLEVEL) = 3                          3
 Notify Level                              (NOTIFYLEVEL) = 3                          3
 Diagnostic data directory path               (DIAGPATH) = /home/tsminst1/sqllib/db2dump/ /home/tsminst1/sqllib/db2dump/
 Current member resolved DIAGPATH                        = /home/tsminst1/sqllib/db2dump/ /home/tsminst1/sqllib/db2dump/
 Alternate diagnostic data directory path (ALT_DIAGPATH) =
 Current member resolved ALT_DIAGPATH                    =
 Size of rotating db2diag & notify logs (MB)  (DIAGSIZE) = 1024                       1024

 Default database monitor switches
   Buffer pool                         (DFT_MON_BUFPOOL) = ON                         ON
   Lock                                   (DFT_MON_LOCK) = OFF                        OFF
   Sort                                   (DFT_MON_SORT) = OFF                        OFF
   Statement                              (DFT_MON_STMT) = OFF                        OFF
   Table                                 (DFT_MON_TABLE) = OFF                        OFF
   Timestamp                         (DFT_MON_TIMESTAMP) = ON                         ON
   Unit of work                            (DFT_MON_UOW) = OFF                        OFF
 Monitor health of instance and databases   (HEALTH_MON) = OFF                        OFF

 SYSADM group name                        (SYSADM_GROUP) = TSMINST1                   TSMINST1
 SYSCTRL group name                      (SYSCTRL_GROUP) =
 SYSMAINT group name                    (SYSMAINT_GROUP) =
 SYSMON group name                        (SYSMON_GROUP) =

 Client Userid-Password Plugin          (CLNT_PW_PLUGIN) =

 Client Kerberos Plugin                (CLNT_KRB_PLUGIN) =

 Group Plugin                             (GROUP_PLUGIN) =

 GSS Plugin for Local Authorization    (LOCAL_GSSPLUGIN) =

 Server Plugin Mode                    (SRV_PLUGIN_MODE) = UNFENCED                   UNFENCED

 Server List of GSS Plugins      (SRVCON_GSSPLUGIN_LIST) =

 Server Userid-Password Plugin        (SRVCON_PW_PLUGIN) = dsmdb2pw                   dsmdb2pw

 Server Connection Authentication          (SRVCON_AUTH) = NOT_SPECIFIED              NOT_SPECIFIED
 Cluster manager                                         =

 Database manager authentication        (AUTHENTICATION) = SERVER                     SERVER
 Alternate authentication           (ALTERNATE_AUTH_ENC) = NOT_SPECIFIED              NOT_SPECIFIED
 Cataloging allowed without authority   (CATALOG_NOAUTH) = NO                         NO
 Trust all clients                      (TRUST_ALLCLNTS) = YES                        YES
 Trusted client authentication          (TRUST_CLNTAUTH) = CLIENT                     CLIENT
 Bypass federated authentication            (FED_NOAUTH) = NO                         NO

 Default database path                       (DFTDBPATH) = /tsm/tsminst1              /tsm/tsminst1

 Database monitor heap size (4KB)          (MON_HEAP_SZ) = AUTOMATIC(90)              AUTOMATIC(90)
 Java Virtual Machine heap size (4KB)     (JAVA_HEAP_SZ) = 2048                       2048
 Audit buffer size (4KB)                  (AUDIT_BUF_SZ) = 0                          0
 Global instance memory (4KB)          (INSTANCE_MEMORY) = AUTOMATIC(45776043)        AUTOMATIC(45776043)
 Member instance memory (4KB)                            = GLOBAL                     GLOBAL
 Agent stack size                       (AGENT_STACK_SZ) = 1024                       1024
 Sort heap threshold (4KB)                  (SHEAPTHRES) = 0                          0

 Directory cache support                     (DIR_CACHE) = YES                        YES

 Application support layer heap size (4KB)   (ASLHEAPSZ) = 15                         15
 Max requester I/O block size (bytes)         (RQRIOBLK) = 65535                      65535
 Workload impact by throttled utilities(UTIL_IMPACT_LIM) = 10                         10

 Priority of agents                           (AGENTPRI) = SYSTEM                     SYSTEM
 Agent pool size                        (NUM_POOLAGENTS) = AUTOMATIC(100)             AUTOMATIC(100)
 Initial number of agents in pool       (NUM_INITAGENTS) = 0                          0
 Max number of coordinating agents     (MAX_COORDAGENTS) = AUTOMATIC(200)             AUTOMATIC(200)
 Max number of client connections      (MAX_CONNECTIONS) = AUTOMATIC(MAX_COORDAGENTS) AUTOMATIC(MAX_COORDAGENTS)

 Keep fenced process                        (KEEPFENCED) = YES                        YES
 Number of pooled fenced processes         (FENCED_POOL) = AUTOMATIC(MAX_COORDAGENTS) AUTOMATIC(MAX_COORDAGENTS)
 Initial number of fenced processes     (NUM_INITFENCED) = 0                          0

 Index re-creation time and redo index build  (INDEXREC) = RESTART                    RESTART

 Transaction manager database name         (TM_DATABASE) = 1ST_CONN                   1ST_CONN
 Transaction resync interval (sec)     (RESYNC_INTERVAL) = 180                        180

 SPM name                                     (SPM_NAME) = prt2atsm                   prt2atsm
 SPM log size                          (SPM_LOG_FILE_SZ) = 256                        256
 SPM resync agent limit                 (SPM_MAX_RESYNC) = 20                         20
 SPM log path                             (SPM_LOG_PATH) =

 TCP/IP Service name                          (SVCENAME) = 51500                      51500
 Discovery mode                               (DISCOVER) = SEARCH                     SEARCH
 Discover server instance                (DISCOVER_INST) = ENABLE                     ENABLE

 SSL server keydb file                   (SSL_SVR_KEYDB) =
 SSL server stash file                   (SSL_SVR_STASH) =
 SSL server certificate label            (SSL_SVR_LABEL) =
 SSL service name                         (SSL_SVCENAME) =
 SSL cipher specs                      (SSL_CIPHERSPECS) =
 SSL versions                             (SSL_VERSIONS) =
 SSL client keydb file                  (SSL_CLNT_KEYDB) =
 SSL client stash file                  (SSL_CLNT_STASH) =

 Maximum query degree of parallelism   (MAX_QUERYDEGREE) = ANY                        ANY
 Enable intra-partition parallelism     (INTRA_PARALLEL) = NO                         NO

 Maximum Asynchronous TQs per query    (FEDERATED_ASYNC) = 0                          0

 No. of int. communication buffers(4KB)(FCM_NUM_BUFFERS) = AUTOMATIC(4096)            AUTOMATIC(4096)
 No. of int. communication channels   (FCM_NUM_CHANNELS) = AUTOMATIC(2048)            AUTOMATIC(2048)
 Inter-node comm. parallelism          (FCM_PARALLELISM) = 1                          1
 Node connection elapse time (sec)         (CONN_ELAPSE) = 10                         10
 Max number of node connection retries (MAX_CONNRETRIES) = 5                          5
 Max time difference between nodes (min) (MAX_TIME_DIFF) = 60                         60

 db2start/db2stop timeout (min)        (START_STOP_TIME) = 10                         10

 WLM dispatcher enabled                 (WLM_DISPATCHER) = NO                         NO
 WLM dispatcher concurrency            (WLM_DISP_CONCUR) = COMPUTED(480)              COMPUTED
 WLM dispatcher CPU shares enabled (WLM_DISP_CPU_SHARES) = NO                         NO
 WLM dispatcher min. utilization (%) (WLM_DISP_MIN_UTIL) = 5                          5

 Communication buffer exit library list (COMM_EXIT_LIST) =

 Current effective arch level         (CUR_EFF_ARCH_LVL) = V:10 R:5 M:0 F:3 I:a SB:0  V:10 R:5 M:0 F:3 I:a SB:0
 Current effective code level         (CUR_EFF_CODE_LVL) = V:10 R:5 M:0 F:3 I:a SB:33 V:10 R:5 M:0 F:3 I:a SB:33
```

Comment: Can you please post your database manager configuration on Linux?  (output from `db2 get dbm cfg`) and any entries from `db2diag.log` that are generated when the client tries to connect?

Comment: Added cfg information... and don't seem to see any activity on db2diag.log (or logs in `/home/tsminst1/sqllib/db2dump/`)

Comment: Is this a full version of DB2 or was this packaged with another product (TSM)?  Often the packaged versions don't include full licenses, and may restrict certain features.  Your server is configured to use a security plugin  (`SRVCON_PW_PLUGIN = dsmdb2pw`) that's not part of a standard DB2 install, so you'd have to know how to configure users for that security plugin (if it's even possible).

Comment: Packaged as part of TSM (Tivoli Backup). Let me look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this help you:

If set up correctly, the Tivoli® Storage Manager server can automatically trace the user ID and password plug-in (`dsmdb2pw`).
Add the following text to the `$INSTANCE_HOME/sqllib/userprofile` file and restart DB2:

`export DB2_DSMDB2PW_TRACEFILE=filename`

where `filename` is a fully qualified path and file name of a file to which the server has write authority.

After DB2 restarts, trace output is stored in the `dsmdb2pw.trc` file in the `~/sqllib/db2dump/` directory.

[Tracing the User ID/Password plug-in](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSGSG7_7.1.1/com.ibm.itsm.tshoot.doc/r_pdg_traceplugin.html)